# loopback set scope by name in JSON relation

Tags: node.js, scope, relationship, loopbackjs

I'm defining a relation between loopback models and I want to filter it using scope. I define a custom scope in related model JSON definition like this

```
"scopes":{
    "blogID":{"where":{"originalType":"Blog"}}
},
```

and I want to address it in master model by name, something like

```
"oldId":{
  "type": "hasOne",
  "model": "OriginalIds",
  "foreignKey": "iid",
  "scope": "blogID" <------
},
```

this does not work, I have to explicitly set a scope structure there like

```
"scope": {"where":{"originalType":"Blog"}}
```

which leads to code duplication. is it possible to address the scope by name somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you would want to do here is file an ER against the Loopback project to add this as a feature. To me, it makes perfect sense. Issues may be reported here: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues